# Sessions and Cookies in Mobile Application

Tags: session, mobile

I am a newbie to Mobile application development, i got stucked with a query like... Is it possible to use cookies & sessions in mobile browser/Mobile Application ?. if so please provide some resource...

if anybody aware of it, please let me know

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Maybe this link could help: https://www.spotxchange.com/resources/blog/product-pulse/productpulse-why-we-must-move-past-cookies-on-mobile/

Answer (score 2):

sessions work on cookies. cookies work on mobiles (otherwise you'd never be able to sign in to any websites on a mobile device). In short, Yes.

Comment: Hello dan , Thankx for your response and regarding your answer, yeah its possible to sign in using a mobile device ,but the problem is whether those cookies are getting saved in the device,so once i need to log in again, whether i need to give the credentials or the browser will take care ?