# Mobile browsers doesn't support session variables?

Tags: php, javascript, mobile, cookies, jquery-mobile

I have a browser version of my web app and I have some values stored in cookies. Now I am making a mobile version and it seems that my cookies are not working. 
Is it possible to use cookies on mobile devices?

I am trying to perform this code and my php is giving me an empty value:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var session_lang= '<?php if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_LANGUAGE']))
                            echo $_SESSION['SESS_LANGUAGE'];?>';
            if (session_lang!='')
            {
                check_and_change(session_lang);   
            }
    });
```

Is there any other way to store data in internal memory so it can work as cookie?
Does mobile devices support session variables? I am looking on the firebug and I can see that I can create session variable but when I want to read it it is null. 
What could be a problem and how to solve this?

EDIT:
I will put you almost entire code so you can see what am I doing...btw. this code is working normally on PC browser.

Javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function languageChange()
    {
         var lang = $('#websites1 option:selected').val();

        return lang;
    }


    $('#websites1').change(function(e) {                    

        var lang = languageChange();

        var dataString = 'lang=' + lang;

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "pass_value.php",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(response) {

                    check_and_change(response.message);
                 }
        });

        return false;

    });

} );

    function check_and_change(lang)
     {
            switch (lang)
                         { //do something
                          }
    }
```

Then this first part that I have put above is on the actual php site that I am looking and which is opening:

And the last thing is pass_value.php:

```
<?php 
session_start();

$_SESSION['SESS_LANGUAGE'] = $_POST['lang'];

print json_encode(array('message' => $_SESSION['SESS_LANGUAGE']));
die();
?>
```

I really don't know why this code doesn't work on the mobile phones.

Comment: [Take a look at HTML 5 Web Storage](http://www.sitepoint.com/a-better-cookie-html5-and-web-storage/#fbid=PofM_1DrEuA)

Comment: so instead of saving into session variables I am saving into web storage?

Comment: Session ID can be passed via cookies or via GET method, and from what I know - browsers at mobile devices do support cookies. Are you sure your code actually works? Have you even started the session?

Comment: Bad idea since a lot of mobile devices don't have such capability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cookies [definitely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152696/sessions-and-cookies-in-mobile-application) [work](http://www.quora.com/Are-cookies-supported-on-Mobile-devices) on mobile browsers. You say "I am looking on the firebug" which makes me think you aren't really looking at it on a phone.

Have you [started the session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php), and [turned on error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)?

Comment: hi, I am looking on the browsers and on the iOS and on the Android device. Okay let me check those thing that you wrote.

Comment: Then `$_SESSION['SESS_LANGUAGE']` is never set, or it is overwritten/deleted somewhere. To debug this you can either go through the code and do `var_dump($_SESSION);die;` or trace it with something like [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/).

Comment: @denonth You could try a [simple example like this](https://gist.github.com/3437078) to see if sessions are working on your different devices. On the second load on the device it should say ".. was set .."

Comment: yes this example is working on the mobile devices. But I have noticed that session variable is saved when I am using my program and when I refresh it then it is not set. Or maybe its not set in the first place?! But I am not receiving any error

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation and discovered that, before my tablet called the script I specified in the URL parameter of the `.ajax( )` call, it was actually calling the `index.php` script again.

Same with my phone.  Since I had initialized my session variables in `index.php`, they kept getting re-set to their initial values (making it look like they were not being correctly stored between pages).

I never figured out why `index.php` was getting re-called, but I added `if !isset( )` checks around the initialization statements and that cleared it up.

Answer (score -1):

On Android, turning on "Data Saver" effectively destroyed my session. I have a login script which will redirect to the previous page when login succeeds. Worked until I turned on Data Saver. Turning it off made it work again. Google does state that Data Saver may affect secure pages which I guess includes my script, which is not on a HTTPS website.