# Advice on Where to Start with My App

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm a relative beginner using Google Apps Script and JavaScript, but I've been playing around with bot for days now and I've created a few simple programs and I'd really like to try and get started on my dream project, even if it takes me forever. I'd like some advice on what I should use in terms of making the UI and what database I should use to hold the information (and if this app is even possible).

**The App**
I'd like to create an online novel management app that utilizes Google Drive as it's source for files. The UI would have a tree that showcases all the google drive files in the novel. When a scene is clicked, the scene opens up for editting.

**Questions**

1. Is this app a possibility?
2. If so, in terms of a UI, what do you think I should use? The google
   provided UIbuilder? The HTML service - for example, can I have a
   frame on the right that the google doc   that needs to be editted
   can open up in on the right?
3. Lastly, what database should I use? The database would have to store
   chapter names and   positions, as well as scene names, positions,
   and the google doc ID that the scene corresponds to. I've got a
   handle on ScriptDB and Spreadsheets... And if either of these two
   aren't the best option, would some other database work better? And
   why?

This app will, hopefully, be able to give an overview of a novel in tree form, allow you to open a particular scene and edit it, create new scenes, and also change the order in which the scenes are displayed. And then when the person finishes their novel, the app will compile all the scenes into one novel (also in google Drive).

Any insight or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: May I suggest that you remove the javascript tag - as for your other post about string array splitting it will generate a lot of answers from people that are not necessary aware of GAS tools (see answer below) and that won't help you in any way (I see already a 'close' on your post).  The situation you explain seems very clear to me... I did hesitate to answer because I have no "for sure" answer, just my personal opinion... but I think I'll do it after all ;-)

Comment: I will delete the JavaScript tag. Thanks for the input - sometimes I don't know which tags to include. But any input you'd be willing to offer would be appreciated, even if it's not strictly GAS. I'm a newbie, so I might find that there is a better way of doing things! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a look at the questions you recently posted I think I have a pretty good idea of what you are trying to do and it looks like an exciting project... I can only encourage you to start it as soon as you can even if you're not comfortable with all the tools you will need to use, the best learning method is probably to work on something important to you.

Now your 3 questions : 1 - This is perfectly doable in the GAS environment and shouldn't be too hard to go through.

2 - the GUI builder is an easy way to start with UI but it lacks a number of features and tools that you will be needing (tree for example ) and is not so easy to expand if you ever need to.  Depending on your knowledge in html, the choice is mainly between UiApp and html service... I would choose UiApp because I'm not good at all in html (but that's not relevant here ;-) but both are capable of building what you want, are easily expandable and not too hard to debug. The advantage could go to html service if you are going to look for 'nice looking features' because it opens the door to 3rd party tools... but again, this is a matter of personal choice.

3 - [A recent post from Mogsdad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15145918/what-is-faster-scriptdb-or-spreadsheetapp/15149959#15149959) showed that spreadsheet are faster than scriptDb for data storage and manipulation. I find it also easier since I can have a global view on data in the spreadsheet when debugging. Of course Spreadsheet must be considered as a container and data manipulated at array level to benefit from maximum performance. I use that in a lot of database application with full satisfaction.

Sorry for these "general considerations" that don't comply to sto standards ;-)

Comment: Thank you! I actually found your answer very helpful! I am pretty good with HTML, so I might look into doing it that way - but not before looking into UiApp. I was leaning toward spreadsheets because I'm much better at working with them than ScriptDB, so that sounds like the route I will take. Thanks so much for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it seems that all of the things you are requesting are not too ridiculous. I recommend sticking to Google services because they are all easily integrated. To start off, you may want to use the UI builder/[UI services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp). There may be a point in this project where you may want some functionality that the UiApp doesn't provide. At that point, you might want to switch over to HtmlService.

My answer is the same for the databases question. You might want to use a spreadsheet for your database so that you will be able to easily edit it by hand if you need to. You may not have the performance that another database would give you, but it will be fairly easy to test and mess around with your spreadsheet "database."

Comment: I've had multiple people suggest Spreadsheet database and HTML service now, so that's probably the direction I'll be going in! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You could start out with getting the basics down. There's a serious amount of data out there. I would suggest you research on an "as-needed" basis. Design some work-/dataflow patterns for your app, for which you could try to use the [Fluid UI extension for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fluid-ui/obgmmkbgpilmggfkhganmcmpemnhimgg?hl=en-US&utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher). Have a look at [this](https://marketplace.firefox.com/developers/) from Mozilla on the designing of apps.

When you've gone through this you might want to have a look at [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) and [the basics of web development](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web_Development/Introduction_to_Web_development) and how you could combine the two.

There's also several ways of using/storing data. You could try [WebSQL](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/) though it they no longer develop it. You could look at [IndexedDB](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/). You could try to use [cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152696/sessions-and-cookies-in-mobile-application).

Seriously, have a look around. You might also like the books of [Wrox](http://www.wrox.com). They're very informative and have great work with reading demo's. Though the books are huge ;)

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about these resources! I'll definitely be taking a look at all of these things to find the best avenue for my app!